# Верно ли, что все байты объекта всегда располагаются "дальше" его адреса?

Tags: c, указатели, объекты

Во всех найденных мною источниках по языку **С** считается, что адрес объекта - это адрес его первого байта (ближайшего к началу адресации, то есть к нулю).

В общем случае, когда мы пишем:

```
void *p = &object;
```

Мы получаем адрес первого байта объекта. И если объект состоит более чем из одного байта, следующие байты данного объекта гарантированно располагаются *дальше* адреса этого объекта.

Иначе говоря, адреса байтов многобайтового объекта >= &object.

Это, безусловно, так на всех платформах, с которыми я сталкивался...

Но почему это так? Найти информацию об этом в **Стандарте** я не смог.

Есть ли какие-то оговорки и исключения для такого положения вещей? Наверняка есть платформы, где все не так.

В общем, буду рад любой дополнительной информации.

Comment: Думаю это так потому что процессоры так работают и другого, при этом логичного, способа человечество не придумало. И в стандарте языка C это не описано потому, что это относится к работе машин как таковых, вне зависимости от используемого языка

Comment: Данные растут вверх (стек - вниз). Если задать адрес не-первого байта - как понять, где оно начинается? других-то чисел (размеры, смещения) нет. А если заложить некое постоянное смещение - так для малых объектов можно вообще мимо попасть. Вот и приходится давать адрес первого байта...

Comment: @Akina так-то размер большинства типов (int, float, struct, union и т. д.) фиксирован (в пределах платформы и компилятора) и известен заранее, смещение для них вычислить нетрудно

Comment: Хотя вот какой-нибудь malloc уже ничего о типах и смещениях не знает

Comment: @Максим [Наверняка есть платформы, где все не так.] Наверняка можно сделать платформу, где это будет не так, но зачем? Пока что аппаратные архитектуры таковы, что это так. И в том числе поэтому язык Си (как портабельный ассемблер) так широко распространен.

Comment: Это всего-лишь история кто первым придумал тот и сделал. Вполне могло быть всё наоборот. Стек с нулевых адресов вниз. А данные в куче примерно так `vec[i]=vec-i;`.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Тогда уж стек с нулевых адресов вверх. Однако стек это довольно позднее изобретение. В частности, на IBM360 aka ЕС ЭВМ никакого стека не было. Поэтому и получилось так, что объекты адресуются в плюс памяти, а стек в минус памяти.

Comment: Меня просто интересует, где в Стандарте сказано хотя бы что-то о том, что адрес объекта, это адрес его первого ближайшего к нулю байта?

Comment: @Максим [адрес его первого ближайшего к нулю байта?] А там может это и не сказано. Арифметикой указателей гарантируется, что при инкременте указателя Вы ползете по объекту. А что там реально подставляет транслятор при инкременте указателя в общем случае никому не ведомо. Как-то я работал на Си для Intel-51 приснопамятной однокристаллке. Там вообще нет аппаратного стека, однако был т.н. компилированный стек и все объекты стековых кадров всех функций лежали, перекрывая друг друга, в ОЗУ. И ничего, все работало.

Comment: *размер большинства типов (int, float, struct, union и т. д.) фиксирован (в пределах платформы и компилятора) и известен заранее, смещение для них вычислить нетрудно* У тебя есть адрес (сегмент:смещение). А вот теперь расскажи мне, как по нему определить тип данных. А заодно расскажи, что будешь делать, если это union.

Comment: @Максим Кстати, есть же еще выравнивание объектов в памяти. То есть когда Вы приведете указатель на объект к указателю на байт и попытаетесь ползти по объекту инкрементом указателя, то в общем случае (если включено выравнивание) Вы будете иногда попадать на мусорные байты, не принадлежащие объекту.

Comment: @Akina у указателей как бы тоже есть типы, по которым можно вычислить все размеры и смещения. Но, как я отметил ниже, malloc об этом всё равно ничего не знает

Comment: @andreymal *у указателей как бы тоже есть типы* НЕТ. Указатель - это адрес. Напиши функцию, которая принимает единственный параметр, являющийся адресом. И попробуй в ней определить, адресом чего именно он является. А если некий код может это определить - значит, адрес на самом деле является объектом, в котором дополнительно есть компонент, хранящий сведения о типе. Либо имеется сторонний диспетчер, который знает, по какому адресу какой тип данных расположен.

Comment: @Akina тип указателя является частью сигнатуры функции. Если попытаться передать указатель не того типа, который указан в функции, компилятор (gcc) заругается «passing argument N of ‘функция’ from incompatible pointer type» и ещё добавит  «expected ‘тип1 *’ but argument is of type ‘тип2 *’». Это всё рулится компилятором, а не в рантайме.

Comment: *Если попытаться передать указатель не того типа, который указан в функции, компилятор (gcc) заругается* Это как раз случай стороннего диспетчера. Т.е. информация о типе - не свойство адреса в рантайме, а свойство лексемы в исходном коде.

Comment: @Akina да, я об этом и говорю, и это вполне позволяет высчитать почти все размеры и смещения во время компиляции. (Если не учитывать malloc, который умеет только void*)

Comment: Спокойно, уберите свои ножи...) И помогите найти официальный источник, где описывается всем привычное поведение оператора &, который возвращает адрес байта объекта, ближайшего к нулю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Иначе говоря, адреса байтов многобайтового объекта >= &object.

Этого прямо требует стандарт:

> #### C99 6.3.2.3/7
>
> ... When a pointer to an object is
> converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the **lowest addressed byte** of
> the object. Successive increments of the result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers
> to the remaining bytes of the object.

Вольный перевод:

> ... Когда указатель на объект преобразуется в указатель на символьный тип, результат будет указывать на *байт с наименьшим адресом* этого объекта. Последовательные инкременты результата (вплоть до размера объекта) дают указатели на остальные байты объекта.

Comment: Но формулировка *самый младший байт* объекта, вносит некоторую путаницу с порядком байтов многобайтовых объектов.

Comment: подправил......